# SQL(erro) - Chamar valores de tabela para função do Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

estou tentando fazer uma busca de objetos por coordenadas passadas por uma tabela que envio pra o banco de dados no qual estou realizando a busca. O script é o seguinte:

```
SELECT 
  win.ID as ID, p.x, p.y, p.cor, p.eq as coef, g.cor1

FROM Informations as p, mydb.windows as win
  
join dbo.fgetnearbycoordeq(win.x,  win.y, 40) n
on
p.value1 = n.value1
join  Additions as g
on
n.value1 = g.value1

WHERE                 
   p.z between win.z_min and win.z_maz
```

A função `dbo.fgetnearbycoordeq` já é do banco sql usado e dá todos os objetos dentro de uma raio de 40 cm tomando como centro as coordenadas `win.x` e `win.y` que passei pela tabela que upei e "chamei" através de `mydb`.

O erro apresentado é

```
The multi-part identifier "win.x" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "win.y" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "p.value1" could not be bound.
```

Agradeço a todos desde já pela ajuda e possível dicas.

Comment: esse join não está correto, o join deve ser entre tabelas e não com o retorno da função, isso funcionaria num `where`, assim por exemplo `where p.value1 = dbo.fgetnearbycoordeq(win.x,  win.y, 40)`, mas além disso a tabela "win" não está ligada a nada, talvez seja necessário fazer isso numa subquery

Comment: Vc poderia me sugerir alguma referência de como fazer essa possível subquery, amigo ?

Comment: precisa procurar no site, mas antes vamos fazer um teste, se funcionar eu escrevo uma resposta detalhando...  veja se funciona: `FROM Informations as p JOIN (SELECT n.* from mydb.windows as win join dbo.fgetnearbycoordeq(win.x,  win.y, 40) n) sub ON p.value1 = sub.value1 ....`

Comment: ou a subquery tbm podeira ser algo assim: `( select dbo.fgetnearbycoordeq(win.x,  win.y, 40) as value1 from mydb.windows as win)`

Comment: Essa subquery ficaria no bloco `FROM` ou `SELECT`, amigo ?

Comment: sim no `from`, a subquery pode ser "uma tabela" no `from`, por exemplo `from tabelaA join (select ....) tabelaB on tabelaA.id = tabelaB.id`.. isso é só um exemplo genérico só pra ilustrar :)

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que vi os valores retornados pela função não são retornados no resultado da consulta, então acho que uma possibilidade seria executar a função na clausula *Where* utilizando o operador *Exists*:

```
SELECT 
  win.ID as ID, 
  p.x, 
  p.y, 
  p.cor, 
  p.eq as coef, 
  g.cor1
FROM Informations as p
INNER JOIN mydb.windows as win 
  ON p.z between win.z_min and win.z_maz
INNER JOIN Additions as g
  on p.value1 = g.value1
WHERE
  EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.fgetnearbycoordeq(win.x,  win.y, 40) n
     WHERE p.value1 = n.value1)
```

Espero que ajude